The sum $s(k)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2^n}+1)}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2^n}-k)}$ gives weird fractions
I stumbled across a series while playing around with a functional equation, it looks like this:
$$s(k)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2^n}+1)}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2^n}-k)}$$
Mathematica gives interesting fractions for the first couple of values of $k$. Starting with $k=0$ and incrementing by $1$, they are:
$$1, -\frac{2}{3},\frac{8}{7}, -\frac{328}{105}, \frac{1088}{93}, -\frac{108608}{1953}, \dots$$
But Mathematica wasn't able to evaluate the sum for a generic positive integer $k$. So, can you $\Gamma$-wizards tell me if there's a way of getting those fractions without numerically evaluating the sum?
EDIT: I should say where I got that sum from! I was thinking about a series
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(x^{1/2^n}-1)$$
which satisfied the equation $f(x^2)=f(x)+x-1$. I noticed that this is similar to $\ln(x^2)=\ln(x)+\ln(x)$, expecially because $\ln(x) \approx x - 1$ near $1$. So this function $f(x)$ is kind of like a undercooked logarithm or something. So I wanted to find a Taylor series of $f(x)$ near $x = 1$ and after a some algebra I got:
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2^n}+1)}{(k+1)!\cdot\Gamma(\frac{1}{2^n}-k)}(x-1)^{k+1}$$ which is how I got to the sum

The numerators all seem to be a power of a 2 times a prime. Do you have more terms?

@SidharthGhoshal, yes! They are: $1, -\frac{2}{3},\frac{8}{7}, -\frac{328}{105}, \frac{1088}{93}, -\frac{108608}{1953}, \frac{3783296}{11811}, -\frac{6526775936}{3011805}, \frac{2879286441984}{171003595}, -\frac{166726947657728}{1128623727}, \dots$

Also, if we divide by $(k+1)!$ which I would give us Taylor coefficients, we get: $1, -\frac{1}{3}, \frac{4}{21}, -\frac{41}{315}, \frac{136}{1395}, -\frac{6788}{87885}, \frac{236456}{3720465}, -\frac{50990437}{948718575}, \frac{833126864}{17955377475}, -\frac{651277139288}{15998241330225}, \dots$

So the numerators not scaled by factorial are divisible by $1,2,2^3,2^3,2^6,2^6,2^7,2^7,2^{11},2^{11}$… I wonder if that repetition can be proven. With more terms I also wonder if the exponent of these powers of 2 has a pattern.

The next ten numerators are $303342484592865280, 637649740483937447936, 50901683649459414679552, 371779075490297168680173568, 7082284858970405952865075200, 20592648314413024524617344251559936, 2507154239569062605575256782457025855488, 342831564209709281616614938894844130492416, 5692560843608990446376418400858647647280431104, 723834665281470408243049003251257631172634693599232$

Using Stirling numbers of the first kind, $$s(k)=\sum_{j=0}^k{k+1\brack j+1}\frac{(-1)^j}{2^{j+1}-1}$$

Comment
Rearranging things ... it seems we get exponential generating function $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}(1+x)^{2^{-n}-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{s(k)}{k!}x^k .$$
Is there a nice formula for $s(k)$ from this?

That look cool! Could you explain how you got that? I was looking at the solution to the functional equation $f(x^2)=f(x) + x - 1$ and I got that sum from trying to write a Taylor series near $x=1$ with $s(k)$ being my coefficients. What I got was a function that diverges at $x=0$ while your LHS doesn't seem to do that

@Loading-146Complete $$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \left(\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2^n}+1\right) x^k}{\Gamma
\left(\frac{1}{2^n}-k\right) k!}\right)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{\Gamma
\left(\frac{1}{2^n}+1\right) x^k}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2^n}-k\right) k!}\right)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }
\frac{(1+x)^{-1+2^{-n}} \Gamma \left(2^{-n} \left(1+2^n\right)\right)}{\Gamma \left(2^{-n}\right)}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }
2^{-n} (1+x)^{-1+2^{-n}}$$

I don't understand the second equality, I'm sorry... I truly am a $\Gamma$-profane... Also, I was looking into the sum:
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2^n}+1)}{(k+1)!\cdot\Gamma(\frac{1}{2^n}-k)}(x-1)^{k+1}\right)$$ and it has completely different properties from your double summation. Mine diverges an $x=0$, monotonically increases, and equals zero at $x=1$ while yours seems to monotonically decrease. It makes me concerned...

"explain how you got that" .... I wrote the quotient of gammas in terms of binomial coefficient $$\binom{2^{-n}}{k+1}$$ and used Newton's binomial theorem.

Okay! This gives $$ s(k)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}\cdot(2^{-n}-1)\cdot \dots \cdot(2^{-n}-k) $$ but this still doesn't give the explicit formula for the fractions because I don't know how to evaluate this sum...

Consider
$$ S(k,a)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a^n(a^n-1)\cdots(a^n-k)$$
Now inside the sum, consider the product $$P(x,k)=x(x-1)\cdots(x-k)$$
This is clearly a polynomial in $x$, so we can write:
$$ P(x,k)=\sum_{m=1}^{k+1}\alpha_m x^m$$ with the coefficients $\alpha_m$ to be determined. Now it follows that:
\begin{align*}
 S(k,a) =&\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(a^n,k) \\
 =&\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^{k+1}\alpha_m a^{mn} \\
 =&\sum_{m=1}^{k+1}\alpha_m\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(a^m\right)^n \\
 =&\sum_{m=1}^{k+1}\alpha_m\frac{a^m}{1-a^m}
\end{align*}
So, in your case, the series would be:
$$s(k)=S(k,1/2)=\sum_{m=1}^{k+1}\frac{\alpha_m}{2^m-1} $$
The coefficients $\alpha_m$ turn out to be just the Stirling numbers of the first kind $s(k+1,m)$ by definition. So the closed form you are looking for is
$$s(k)=\sum_{m=1}^{k+1}\frac{s(k+1,m)}{2^m-1} $$
I did some research but couldn't find any closed form for this.
